# Typescript error for "app.ws" using express-ws

Tags: typescript, express, raspberry-pi

In my small project, I want to build a BabyCam that can be accessed from any web browser using a Raspberry Pi Zero. For this, I would like to open a web socket using express-is to stream video to several clients. I am basing most of the video-related code on the [raspivid-stream module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raspivid-stream). However, when trying to access the web socket, I get a type error for `app.ws(...` stating `Property 'ws' does not exist on type 'Application'`. Of course, I imported both the typings for express and express-ws.

I am not really sure, what the problem is as the same call in JavaScript appears work fine. Here's the code - I am glad for any help!

```
import express from 'express';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';
import http from 'http';
import raspividStream from 'raspivid-stream';
import expressWs from 'express-ws';


const server: express.Application = express();

const httpPort: number = 8080;
const httpsPort: number = 8443;

const sslCredentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/localhost.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../ssl/localhost.cert', 'utf8')
};

// CREATE SERVER

const httpServer = http.createServer(server);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(sslCredentials, server);

expressWs(server, httpsServer);

// ROUTES

server.get('*', (req: Request, res:Response) => {
    if (!req.secure) {
        return res.redirect(`https://${req.hostname}:${httpsPort}${req.originalUrl}`);
    }
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

// WEBSOCKET

server.ws('/video-stream', (ws) => {
    console.log('Client connected');


    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
    action: 'init',
    width: '960',
    height: '540'
    }));

    var videoStream = raspividStream({ rotation: 180 });

    videoStream.on('data', (data) => {
        ws.send(data, { binary: true }, (error) => { if (error) console.error(error); });
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client left');
        videoStream.removeAllListeners('data');
    });
});


// START SERVER

httpServer.listen(httpPort, () => {
    console.log(`BabyCam (redirect) listening at http://localhost:${httpPort}/`);
}); 

httpsServer.listen(httpsPort, () => {
    console.log(`BabyCam (SSL) listening at https://localhost:${httpsPort}/`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express.Application does not have a member called ws. That's the error you get. You need to use the return value of expressWS(server, httpsServer). The app you can access there is typed as Express.Application & WithWebsocketMethod.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! With your info, I checked my imports of express and express-ws and changed them into the following:
`var express = require('express');
const server = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(server);`
As you have probably noticed I am pretty new to the whole thing and I don't really see the difference between `import express from 'express';`and `const express = require('express');`but it worked - thanks again!

Answer (score 10):

`Property 'ws' does not exist on type 'Application'` is a *typescript* error, indicating that typescript is not aware of a `ws()` method on `app`.  This is expected because `ws()` is not a part of the default `express` API, and so the TS types (`@types/express`) don't define it.

The `ws()` method comes from the `express-ws` module as a "mix in".  The `express-ws` types (`@types/ws-express`) *do* define this, but the code needs to be structured to allow Typescript to be aware of this ...

First, make sure you have TS types for `express` and `express-ws` installed:

```
npm install @types/express @types/express-ws
```

Then create `server` as follows:

```js
const expressServer = express();           // Type = Express 
const wsServer = expressWs(expressServer); // Type = expressWs.Instance
const server = wsServer.app;               // type = wsExpress.Application
```

Defining the code in this way gives `server` the expressWs.Application type, [defined here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-ws/index.d.ts#L17C46-L17C65) (which includes the `WithWebsocketMethod` declaration for `ws()` [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-ws/index.d.ts#L40-L42))

NOTE: The runtime value of `server` and `expressServer` is identical at runtime.  It's the same exact Express instance (which is why your code works fine when run as plain JS).  We're just handling things slightly differently to keep Typescript informed of what's happening with the types.

Comment: this helped mathieu. but I couldn't get it to run

Comment: You may want to have a look at the following file: https://github.com/mathieucaroff/pixelpony/blob/a7c26df7ed068e7742fe521f2aaa77f0bd0204f6/package/server/src/server.ts -- this is how I eventually got it to work. You may want to  check my `tsconfig.json` (`tsconfig.base.json` actually), as it may impact the way Typescript treats imports.

Comment: What is this doing? export type Server = (param: ServerParam) => expressWs.Application

export const server: Server = (param) => {

Comment: Let's discuss the matter in [this github issue](https://github.com/mathieucaroff/pixelpony/issues/6)